# unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to follow this example. I can't get it to compile. Any ideas on how to resolve the issue?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

function log(className)
{
  console.log(className)

  return (...args) => {
    console.log("Arguments passed to this class's constructor are ", args)
    return new className(...args)
  }
}

@log
class myExampleClass
{
    constructor(arg1, arg2)
    {
      console.log("Constructor fired!")
    }
}

const myClass = new myExampleClass(5,10)
```

The error i'm getting is.

```
Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type '(...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'typeof myExampleClass'.
    Type '(...args: any[]) => any' provides no match for the signature 'new (arg1: any, arg2: any): myExampleClass'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class decorator is applied to the constructor of the class and can be used to observe, modify, or **replace a class definition**.

In your example you're trying to replace a class definition. In that case you have to return type of the same class your `@log` decorator is applied to.

```
function log<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {} }>(className: T) {
  console.log(className)
  return class extends className {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      console.log("Arguments passed to this class's constructor are ", args)
    }
  }
}
```

See also:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators

Comment: is there an example on how to modify a class (for example, wrapping methods if they happen to be there, etc) ?